# Removing a lit-element component, re-creating/rendering?

Tags: custom-element, lit-element

Trying to: (1) delete contents of a container (div); (2) render a lit-element component into that container; (3) repeat...
Here's the code:

```
let count = 1;

window.customElements.define('ibp-app', class extends LitElement {
  render() { 
    console.log("{#}ibp-app render.");
    return html`<h3>Hello World! -- ${count++}</h3>`;
  }
}); //ibp-app

window.renderToContainer = function () {
  console.log("{#}renderToContainer");
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = ''; //clear container

  //Two cases: #1 works,  #2 doesn't!
    // #1: works, but can't use lit-html template syntax
    //document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '<ibp-app></ibp-app>';

    // #2: doesn't work; after first time, ibp-app not rendered.
    render( html`<ibp-app></ibp-app>`, document.getElementById('container'));
}  

render(
  // Renders a container followed by button.  Each press of button
  // will call renderToContainer to clear the container, then put
  // an new ibp-app component into the container.
  html`
    <div id="container">(Empty Container)</div>
    <button @click=${renderToContainer}>Render to #containter</button>
  `,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

The first time the button is clicked, the ibp-app component replaces the
container's initial text; but further button clicks, leave the container
empty.  It would appear there is something "interesting" about removing
a lit-element component and re-creating it that I've missed.

Any insight would be *greatly* appreciated.

Comment: Could you expand on why you want to re-create the component? Do you want to trigger some kind of refresh?

Comment: It was a matter of running different life cycle methods: e.g. constructor & connectedCallback vs. firstUpdated vs. updated, etc.  I'm coming from years of React, so these lifecycle methods are significantly different from React's, and it was necessary to rethink what code goes with what lifecycle method.  I think litElement could benefit from a more detailed description of this topic. After reading the litElement Guide many times, I still find myself writing and running test cases to figure out how something *really* works!

Comment: litElement is designed to update content inside tag instead of refreshing DOM or tag. Why not set a property and reflect true when button clicks. So when property changes., attributeChangedCallBack triggers and you can requestupdate for DOM value update... for e.g.

`static get properties(){
return {incValue: type: Number; attribute:'increment-value', reflect: true }
}
attributeChangedCallback(){
super.attributeChangedCallback(name,oldVal,newVal){
if(name===increment-value){
this.requestUpdate();
}
_addclick(){
this.incValue++;
}
<paper-button @click='this._addclick()'>

}
}
`

Comment: Yes... you correctly restated the "lit-element way". My point was that for those coming to lit-Element from React, Vue, Angular, and the other most popular frameworks: it is a different way of doing things... a different way of thinking about components. LitElement is, in many ways, beautiful in its simplicity, but I do believe that lit-Element and lit-HTML, could benefit from more detailed documentation, especially in the area of lifecycle: the how/when/why of creation, mutation over component lifetime, and destruction.